# How to specify the location of athena query results when using awswrangler

Tags: amazon-athena, aws-data-wrangler

The python code below can fetch data from a pre-configured athena table when it is run on local computer. But it automatically creates an S3 bucket to store temporary tables and metadata. The automatically created bucket name looks like `aws-athena-query-results-<account_id>-{aws-region>`. Is there a way to specify `awswrangler` to use another S3 location?

```
import awswrangler as wr

db_name = "test_db"
table_name = "test_table"
query = f"SELECT * FROM {db_name}.{table_name}"

df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(sql=query, database=db_name)
```

Comment: May be this be of help; https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/configure-a-custom-amazon-s3-query-output-location-and-data-retention-policy-for-amazon-athena-data-sources-in-amazon-sagemaker-data-wrangler/

Comment: also, you can pass custom path to `s3_output` arg as well.

Comment: @JimsonJames, I saw that link too and it seems relevant. But I am not using SageMaker. `s3_output` did work and you can make that an answer. Ideally, I would like to specify the default S3 so I don't have to provide `s3_output` every time. But it looks like `s3_output` does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `s3_output` for setting custom output path per query as shown below.

```
# Query Athena using the wrangler library
query = "SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 100"
df = wr.athena.read_sql_query(query, database="my_database", s3_output=S3_OUTPUT_LOCATION)
```

There could be some exception like the one raised in this ticket, [User specified s3_output not handled correctly in athena.read_sql_query with unload_approach=True](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-pandas/issues/1200)

Unfortunately there is no way as of now to specify it as part of wrangler [global config](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/021%20-%20Global%20Configurations.html#wr.config).